# Dynamic Table Row Deletion

Tags: javascript

I am creating a dynamic table through Javascript. I am taking no. of row and columns from user and creating table. On second time when user enters I am deleting all present rows and creating new rows. Everything is working fine but for deletion when I am using the commented code it is not working while other one is working fine. Can anybody tell me what is the reason behind this?

//deleting preExisting rows:-

```
for(k=tblObj.rows.length;k>0;k--)
tblObj.deleteRow(k-1);
```

Above Logic is working fine but below one is not working why???

```
            /*for(k=0;k<Number(tblObj.rows.length);k++)
                {   
                    tblObj.deleteRow(k);
                }*/   //This Logic is not working:Why???
```

Comment: *This Logic is not working*: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Do you mind using jQuery? [Flexgrid](http://www.flexigrid.info) is a great tool for creating great tables.

Comment: even if i remove Number() then also problem exists

Comment: @Nivas:- The commented code is not deleting the first row of table and appending new rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tblObj.rows.length value is computed for every loop execution, and the array is getting shorter every time.

Try with

```
var len = tblObj.rows.length;
for(k=0;k<len;k++)
{   
    tblObj.deleteRow(0);
}
```

Comment: there, I suppose it's ok now :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are deleting rows from the beginning you have to delete first row `rowCount` times:

```
var rowCount = tblObj.rows.length;
for(k=0;k<rowCount;k++)
{   
    tblObj.deleteRow(0);
}
```